# Check printer - Convert to English text from the input value.

Tags: code-golf, conversion

Check printer function (or subroutine) - Convert to English text from the input value. 12.34 -> "twelve dollars and thirty four cents". For the range .01 to 9999.99 assuming valid input.

Comment: can we assume that answers could be in codegolf way?

Comment: Is this a function or a whole program?

Comment: Hm... I did this once for MMIX... Wait some time and I change it to satisfy the conditions. That's fun!

Comment: How should 12.00 be written?  "twelve dollars" or "twelve dollars and xx/00" or something?

Comment: You are generally expected to tag questions with a type-of-puzzle tag (so far code-golf or code-challenge). Please correct my edit if I [chose poorly](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ubw5N8iVDHI).

Answer (score 3):

## Common Lisp, 95

Newline not counted in:

```lisp
(lambda(n &aux(d(floor n))(c(round(*(- n d)100))))
(format()"~R dollar~P and ~R cent~P"d d c c))
```

Sample use (assigning it to f):

```lisp
CL-USER> (f .01)
"zero dollars and one cent"
CL-USER> (f 12.34)
"twelve dollars and thirty-four cents"
CL-USER> (f 9999.99)
"nine thousand nine hundred ninety-nine dollars and ninety-nine cents"
```